# How to create an empty environment represented by a function

Tags: sml, ml, mosml

I came across this problem online which I found interesting, it had a decent explanation but I was confused about the solution. So given

```
type 'a fenv = name -> 'a
```

create a value of type

```
'a fenv
```

which would be our empty env. I thought this to be something along the following

```
exception NotFound of name
val empty = fn name => raise NotFound name
```

Where it might return a Notfound name exception but I may be doing this wrong because I continue to get

```
Type clash: expression of type
   'a alist -> 'a alist alist
cannot have type
   'a alist alist
Toplevel input:
val (_: 'a fenv) = empty
Unbound type constructor: fenv
```

Sorry if this is simple still new at sml could someone explain how I would go about getting the solution?

Thanks

Comment: You'll get better help if you post the actual code rather than "...". The trivial implementation of `empty` should work. You might be overthinking it, or having problems in the code that uses it.

Comment: My fault it's been edited

Comment: Looks like the problem is elsewhere. The compiler should be telling  you where the offending expression is. (I suspect that you’re forgetting to apply a function somewhere.)

Comment: I updated the error message after I tried testing it out another way with the following val _ : 'a fenv = fenvEmpty. So I wasn't wrong in calling an exception?

Comment: That's the test case written in the book so I assumed it was correct. Double checking apologies but it is val (_: 'a fenv) = empty

Comment: There is no point in trying to figure out what's wrong without a [mcve]. Please post one.

Comment: I'll rewrite my post to see that its fit to that standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create an empty environment represented by a function

You could do:

```
type name = string
exception NotFound of name
fun empty name = raise NotFound name
```

> I may be doing this wrong because I continue to get
>
> ```
> Type clash: expression of type
>    'a alist -> 'a alist alist
> cannot have type
>    'a alist alist
> ```

You do realize that your code mentions nothing of *'a alist*, right? You're probably either using a REPL that has an outdated definition for `type 'a fenv`, or your file contains multiple definitions, one involving this *'a alist* and another containing this *'a fenv*.

Comment: Thanks Simon I didn't even think of that and going by my own implementation I do think that may be the issue